# 'QtCore' was built against ABI v12 but this module is being built against ABI v13

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, sip, abi

I'm trying to create Python bindings for a C++ Library project (labelex) that uses Qt on Windows 10. I created a C++ qmake project and build my library without problems (MSVC2019 64bit). But when I want to run sip-install it comes to the error message mentioned above.

What can I do to create the Python bindings for my library?

I setup a simple C++ library project using qmake. Futhermore I created the sip project files. I build the c++ project into project subfolder './build/msvc'. Finally I ran sip-install.

## C++ Project Files (qmake)

*labelex.pro*

```
QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += LABELEX_LIBRARY

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    labelex.cpp

HEADERS += \
    labelex_global.h \
    labelex.h

DESTDIR  = ./lib

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

*labelex_global.h*

```
#ifndef LABELEX_GLOBAL_H
#define LABELEX_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(LABELEX_LIBRARY)
#  define LABELEX_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define LABELEX_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // LABELEX_GLOBAL_H
```

*labelex.h*

```
#ifndef LABELEX_H
#define LABELEX_H

#include "labelex_global.h"
#include <QLabel>

class LABELEX_EXPORT Labelex : QLabel
{
public:
    Labelex(QWidget* parent);
};

#endif // LABELEX_H
```

*labelex.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "labelex.h"

Labelex::Labelex(QWidget* parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
    std::cout << "LabelEx created" << std::endl;
}
```

## sip Project Files

*pyproject.toml*

```
# Specify sip v6 as the build system for the package.
[build-system]
requires = ["sip >=6, <7"]
build-backend = "sipbuild.api"

# Specify the PEP 566 metadata for the project.
[tool.sip.metadata]
name = "labelex"

[tool.sip.project]
sip-include-dirs = ["C:/Coding/python/environments/pyqt5_sip/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings"]


# Configure the building of the labelex bindings.
[tool.sip.bindings.labelex]
headers = ["labelex.h"]
include-dirs = ["./"]
libraries = ["labelex"]
library-dirs = ["./build/msvc/lib"]
```

*labelex.sip*

```
// Define the SIP wrapper to the (actual) fib library.

%Module(name=labelex, language="C++")

%Import QtCore/QtCoremod.sip

class LabelEx 
{
%TypeHeaderCode
#include <labelex.h>
%End
};
```

My Python virutal environment looks like this:

```
(pyqt5_sip) C:\Coding\python\projects\sip_example5>pip freeze
packaging==23.1
ply==3.11
PyQt5==5.15.9
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.12.2
sip==6.7.11
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
```

This is the complete output after running sip-install:

```
(pyqt5_sip) C:\Coding\python\projects\sip_example5>sip-install
These bindings will be built: labelex.
Generating the labelex bindings...
sip-install: C:\Coding\python\environments\pyqt5_sip\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\bindings\QtCore\QtCore.toml: 'QtCore' was built against ABI v12 but this module is being built against ABI v13
```